# Create user inside a syscall

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Is it possible to create an user, just like the `useradd` command does, inside a system call on Linux kernel?

I saw somewhere that syscalls cannot use the `exec` family, is it true?

Comment: `useradd` modifies multiple files (`group`, `passwd`, `shadow`) and optionally creates/initializes home directory. Most system calls are more atomic operation like _open file_, _write to it_, _create directory_. What is the point of having this complex system call (considering that user database is not even in kernel)?

Comment: It seems inadvisable to put this sort of logic into a system call.  I think you're better off just documenting the requirement for a particular user to exist, and having the system call fail if for some reason it cannot continue without the necessary user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the kernel, users are identified by their ID (a number), and this is the *only* information that the kernel knows about a user.

As far as the kernel is concerned, users do no need to be created: to make a process have a different user, just call [setuid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) with a different number.

The mapping between user IDs and other information (name, home directory, etc.) is done entirely in user space. And that the user information is stored in files like `/etc/passwd` is just a convention; there are systems that use users differently (e.g. Android gives each app its own user ID).

---

If you really want to execute a user-mode program, call [call_usermodehelper()](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-call-usermodehelper.html).